# Meaning of warm vs hot when talking about weather

Tags: adjectives, logic

Here is the context:

- Warm weather means temperatures around 25°C
- Hot weather is when temperatures are around 35°C

Then if today there is hot weather, what should we understand when one says "I wish it was warmer today" ?

I understand that he/she wishes to have temperatures around 40°C, but you could also interpret it as he/she wishes the temperatures were closer to warm weather i.e. 25°C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with the weather when you come down to it.

> I wish it was warmer today.

"Warmer" does not mean "colder" if the temperature is above a given definition of "warm." It means that the temperature should be higher than it currently is. If the person wants warm, but not hot weather while on a hot day, they might say something like "I wish it were a little cooler today." or "I wish it weren't quite so hot."

Comment: thanks! that was my initial thought, but I was curious if it can, in some weird case, mean something different. I guess not

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely light sarcasm.

Sarcasm because it mocks (with irony) wanting even more heat in hot weather.  Light, because while sarcasm usually is derisive, offensive, light sarcasm, especially when involving one's self, is "victimless".  The speaker hopefully jokes pretending to be desiring warmer weather.

Comment: thank you! I see the light sarcasm, but I took the phrase as a literal example

Answer (score -2):

'Weather' has nothing to do with 'hot'. 'Warm' is used to explain the temperature below average. but 'hot' describes the temperature of objects especially in heat condition.